# GetElementByID with textarea

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I tried to send form data through TinyMCE, but script sends old value, not new.
Form code:

```
<form>
    <textarea id="tml"  name="template_content" class="editor_large">{$template_content|escape}</textarea>
</form>

<input class="button_green button_save" type="button" name="save" value="Save" />
```

JS code:

```
$(function() {  
    // Saving AJAX code
    function save()
    {
        $('#tml').css('background-color','#e0ffe0');
content=document.getElementById("tml").innerHTML        
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ajax/save_template.php',
            data: {'content': content, 'theme':'{/literal}{$theme}{literal}', 'template': '{/literal}{$template_file}{literal}', 'session_id': '{/literal}{$smarty.session.id}{literal}'},
            success: function(data){

                $('#tml').animate({'background-color': '#000000'});
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    }

    // Press Save
    $('input[name="save"]').click(function() {
        save();
    });

    // ctrl+s
    var isCtrl = false;
    var isCmd = false;
    $(document).keyup(function (e) {
        if(e.which == 17) isCtrl=false;
        if(e.which == 91) isCmd=false;
    }).keydown(function (e) {
        if(e.which == 17) isCtrl=true;
        if(e.which == 91) isCmd=true;
        if(e.which == 83 && (isCtrl || isCmd)) {
            save();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

As i think, my script also must change color via css, but it also didnt. 
Save_template.php file:

```
<?php

session_start();

chdir('../..');
require_once('api/Simpla.php');

$simpla = new Simpla();

if(!$simpla->managers->access('design'))
    return false;

// Проверка сессии для защиты от xss
if(!$simpla->request->check_session())
{
    trigger_error('Session expired', E_USER_WARNING);
    exit();
}
$content = $simpla->request->post('content');
$template = $simpla->request->post('template');
$theme = $simpla->request->post('theme', 'string');

if(pathinfo($template, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) != 'tpl')
    exit();

$file = $simpla->config->root_dir.'design/'.$theme.'/html/'.$template;
if(is_file($file) && is_writable($file) && !is_file($simpla->config->root_dir.'design/'.$theme.'/locked'))
    file_put_contents($file, $content);

$result= true;
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: -1");      
$json = json_encode($result);
print $json;
```

In my opinion, problem hides in GetElementByID

Comment: You can use jQuery to get the element value: `$("#tml").val()` - no reason to resort to the browser API if you're already using the library.

Comment: missing both var and semicolon..

Answer (score 6):

It's because the `innerHTML` property doesn't change when you type in the textarea, the `value` does

```
var content = document.getElementById("tml").value;
```

or with jQuery

```
var content = $("#tml").val();
```